# Here.com Routing API to replace Google Maps Directions - can I pass an address in the restful URL query?

Tags: here-api

In Google Maps API there is a call like so: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=[START]&destination=[END]&sensor=false`  You pass the `[START]` and `[END]` values into the URL and it gives you the directions, the time it takes to travel, traffic, etc.

Here Maps offers a similar API: `https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=[API_KEY]&waypoint0=geo![START_LAT_LONG]&waypoint1=geo![END_LAT_LON]&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled`

The issue is: it requires the lat/long of the points, and the function I am trying to replace gets them passed as address strings (ex: `123 Main St Springfield MA 05050`).  Since I don't get them as any other format **I'd like to be able to call the URL with something like this**:

`https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=[API_KEY]&waypoint0=addr![START_ADDRESS_STRING]&waypoint1=geo![END_LAT_LON]&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled`

That format doesn't appear to work, and [the documentation on this functionality](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html) is lacking, offering only `geo!`, `street!` (which appears to mean "use this street" not "start at this address") and `link!` (not even sure what that one is).

I could work around this with a geocoding API, but if that increases my API calls from 1 to 3 (or more if I have more than a start and stop) and it will obviously slow down execution time.  I am NOT attached to this Here.com API call if there is a better option out there for this problem.

### **In summary: is there a way for me to do Here.com routing with address strings?**

Comment: I think there is no service for that instead while doing so just convert  the address by using reverse geocoder and let the lat longs be pushed into the rest api

Comment: As I mentioned originally, the `function I am trying to replace gets them passed as address strings` and I know `I could work around this with a geocoding API, but if that increases my API calls from 1 to 3 (or more if I have more than a start and stop) and it will obviously slow down execution time.`  Trying to avoid doing 3 API calls if I can do 1.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not pass an address in the restful URL query so is designed the HERE Routing API. The API was designed only for waypoints, It does not accept addressees. The address could be used as a hint but not as a full input.

The advantage to utilize Geocoder API first is you can analyse (programmatically or manually) first Geocoder response (select alternatives, check misspelling/typo of an address, etc.) to prepare more precisely coordinates for further a route calculation.

Comment: Doing the geocoding first is the route I had to take unfortunately.  I also had to use the Google API for the geocoding parts since Here's geocoding is fairly poor.  Try `Bradley International Airport` (which is located in Connecticut) for example, and it gives you an intersection near LAX in California: `https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?apiKey=APIKEYHERE&searchtext=Bradley+International+Airport`